# 2011 GMC Sierra 1500 low beams not working

Tags: electrical, troubleshooting, headlight, gmc, sierra

The low beams on my 2011 GMC Sierra 1500 are not working. My high beams work in both switch positions. What is the simplest and cheapest way to fix this problem?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: A 15 amp 15 cent fuse would be the cheapest fix :)

Answer (score 0):

Check a fuse or relay leading to them from your users manual would be a cheap easy fix if one of those went